# ¿Por que salta directo a Pepsi Cola y no la opcion selecionada?

Tags: php

tengo el Index siguiente:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Productos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Productos</h2>
    <hr>
<form method="post" action="productos.php">
    Elige tu producto:
<select name="listings">
     <option value="Seleccionar">Seleccionar</option>
     <option value="cocacola" <?php if($listings1 == "cocacola") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Coca Cola</option>
     <option value="fanta" <?php if($listings2 == "fanta") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Fanta </option>
     <option value="pepsi"  <?php if($listings3 == "pepsi") print('selected="selected"'); ?> >Pepsi</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
Unidades:
<br>
<input type="text" name="Unidades">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Aceptar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

y el archivo **productos.php** con el siguiente codigo fuente:

```
<?php

$value=$_POST["listings"];
$listings1=$_POST['cocacola'];
$listings2=$_POST['fanta'];
$listings3=$_POST['pepsi'];

$precio_pepsi=25;
$precio_fanta=20;
$precio_coca=30;


switch ($listings) { 
    case 
    $listings3:
        echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Pepsi Cola";
        echo "<br>";
            echo "Precio total: ". $precio_pepsi * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
        break;

    case 
    $listings2:
        echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Fanta Naranja";
        echo "<br>";
            echo "Precio total: ". $precio_fanta * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
        break;

    case 
    $listings1:
        echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Coca Cola";
        echo "<br>";
            echo "Precio total: ". $precio_coca * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
        break;

}
?>
```

la pregunta es seleciono fanta pero siempre el resultado me sale coca cola ¿por que suele pasar esto? segun veo parece que no toma las variables se agradece ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esta solución!

```
?php

$valoresListings=$_POST["listings"];
/*
$listings1=$_POST["cocacola"];
$listings2=$_POST["fanta"];
$listings3=$_POST["pepsi"];
*/

$precio_pepsi=25;
$precio_fanta=20;
$precio_coca=30;

switch ($valoresListings) { 

case 'cocacola':

    echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Coca Cola";
    echo "<br>";
        echo "Precio total: ". $precio_coca * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
    break;

case 'fanta':

    echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Fanta Naranja";
    echo "<br>";
        echo "Precio total: ". $precio_fanta * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
break;

case 'pepsi':
    echo "Has pedido ".$_REQUEST['Unidades']." unidades de Pepsi Cola";
    echo "<br>";
        echo "Precio total: ". $precio_pepsi * $_REQUEST['Unidades'];
    break;

default:
    echo "Valor no encontrado";
break;
}

?>
```

La variable $valoresListings me guarda el valor que trae de "listings". y luego segun el valor se programan los respectivo case.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la variable $listings, con la que se inicia el Switch.

```
echo "Valor de listing".listings;
switch ($listings) {
```

La variable $listings no esta trayendo ningun valor.